# Asynchronously and parallelly downloading files

Tags: c#, foreach, task, async-await

**EDIT**

I've changed the title of the question to reflect the issue I had but also an answer on how to achieve this easily.

---

I am trying to make the 2nd method to return `Task<TResult>` instead of `Task` as in 1st method but I am getting a cascade of errors as a consequence of trying to fix it.

- I added `return` before `await body(partition.Current);`
- In turn it asks me to add a return statement below so I added `return null` below
- But now the select statement complains that it cannot infer the type argument from the query
- I change `Task.Run` to `Task.Run<TResult>` but without success.

How can I fix it ?

The first method comes from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/05/10278165.aspx, the second method is the overload that I'm trying to create.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int dop, Func<T, Task> body)
    {
        return Task.WhenAll(
            from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop)
            select Task.Run(async delegate
            {
                using (partition)
                    while (partition.MoveNext())
                        await body(partition.Current);
            }));
    }

    public static Task ForEachAsync<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int dop, Func<T, Task<TResult>> body)
    {
        return Task.WhenAll(
            from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop)
            select Task.Run(async delegate
            {
                using (partition)
                    while (partition.MoveNext())
                        await body(partition.Current);
            }));
    }
}
```

Usage example :

With this method I'd like to download multiple files in parallel and asynchronously :

```
private async void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Artist artist = await GetArtist();
    IEnumerable<string> enumerable = artist.Reviews.Select(s => s.ImageUrl);
    string[] downloadFile = await DownloadFiles(enumerable);
}

public static async Task<string[]> DownloadFiles(IEnumerable<string> enumerable)
{
    if (enumerable == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("enumerable");
    await enumerable.ForEachAsync(5, s => DownloadFile(s));
    // Incomplete, the above statement is void and can't be returned
}

public static async Task<string> DownloadFile(string address)
{
    /* Download a file from specified address, 
        * return destination file name on success or null on failure */

    if (address == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    Uri result;
    if (!Uri.TryCreate(address, UriKind.Absolute, out result))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Couldn't create URI from specified address: {0}", address));
        return null;
    }

    try
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
            await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(address, fileName);
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Downloaded file saved to: {0} ({1})", fileName, address));
            return fileName;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException webException)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Couldn't download file from specified address: {0}", webException.Message));
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you'd expect the result to be. You're passing in a whole sequence of `T` values, and executing the same function on both of them - what single result would you expect to get out of the `Task<TResult>` returned?

Comment: I'd like to get a Task<string> in that case, I've added an example on my question.

Comment: *"With this method I'd like to download multiple files in parallel and asynchronously"* : `Parallel.Foreach` isn't enough?

Comment: @Aybe, would you want it to be an `Task<IEnumerable<string>>` in your case, or what string would you return if you really do want `Task<string>`?

Comment: @L.B I have seen it but couldn't understand it ... particularly on how to fetch the results from it :)

Comment: @MattSmith I was expecting it to return `Task<string>`, the DownloadFiles method would use that ForEachSync overload which in turn would call DownloadFile for each of the item in the enumerable.

Comment: @Aybe I think you still don't understand. Imagine you're downloading two pages, one containing `foo` and the other `bar`. If your `ForEachAsync()` was to return `Task<string>`, what string do you want it to contain? Given your code, it would make much more sense if it returned `Task<string[]>`.

Comment: Oh yes absolutely, I misunderstand what he meant.

Comment: Related: [ForEachAsync with Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907650/foreachasync-with-result)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I solved it and posting it here, might help anyone having the same issue.

My initial need was a small helper that would quickly download images but also just drop the connection if server does not respond quickly, all this **in parallel and asynchronously**.

This helper will return you a tuple that contains the remote path, the local path and the exception if one occurred; so quite useful as it's always good to know why faulty downloads have faulted. I think I forgot none of the situations that can occur for a download but you're welcome to comment it.

- You specify a list of urls to download
- You can specify a local file name where it will be saved, if not one will be generated for you
- Optionally a duration for cancelling a download (handy for slow or unreachable servers)

You can just use `DownloadFileTaskAsync` itself or use the `ForEachAsync` helper for parallel and asynchronous downloads.

Code with an example on how to use it :

```
private async void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable<string> enumerable = your urls here;
    var results = new List<Tuple<string, string, Exception>>();
    await enumerable.ForEachAsync(s => DownloadFileTaskAsync(s, null, 1000), (url, t) => results.Add(t));
}

/// <summary>
///     Downloads a file from a specified Internet address.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="remotePath">Internet address of the file to download.</param>
/// <param name="localPath">
///     Local file name where to store the content of the download, if null a temporary file name will
///     be generated.
/// </param>
/// <param name="timeOut">Duration in miliseconds before cancelling the  operation.</param>
/// <returns>A tuple containing the remote path, the local path and an exception if one occurred.</returns>
private static async Task<Tuple<string, string, Exception>> DownloadFileTaskAsync(string remotePath,
    string localPath = null, int timeOut = 3000)
{
    try
    {
        if (remotePath == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("DownloadFileTaskAsync (null remote path): skipping");
            throw new ArgumentNullException("remotePath");
        }

        if (localPath == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(
                string.Format(
                    "DownloadFileTaskAsync (null local path): generating a temporary file name for {0}",
                    remotePath));
            localPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
        }

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            TimerCallback timerCallback = c =>
            {
                var webClient = (WebClient) c;
                if (!webClient.IsBusy) return;
                webClient.CancelAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("DownloadFileTaskAsync (time out due): {0}", remotePath));
            };
            using (var timer = new Timer(timerCallback, client, timeOut, Timeout.Infinite))
            {
                await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(remotePath, localPath);
            }
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("DownloadFileTaskAsync (downloaded): {0}", remotePath));
            return new Tuple<string, string, Exception>(remotePath, localPath, null);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new Tuple<string, string, Exception>(remotePath, null, ex);
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static Task ForEachAsync<TSource, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, Task<TResult>> taskSelector, Action<TSource, TResult> resultProcessor)
    {
        var oneAtATime = new SemaphoreSlim(5, 10);
        return Task.WhenAll(
            from item in source
            select ProcessAsync(item, taskSelector, resultProcessor, oneAtATime));
    }

    private static async Task ProcessAsync<TSource, TResult>(
        TSource item,
        Func<TSource, Task<TResult>> taskSelector, Action<TSource, TResult> resultProcessor,
        SemaphoreSlim oneAtATime)
    {
        TResult result = await taskSelector(item);
        await oneAtATime.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            resultProcessor(item, result);
        }
        finally
        {
            oneAtATime.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't changed the signature of `ForEachAsync` to choose the level of parallelism, I'll let you adjust it as you wish.

Output example :

```
DownloadFileTaskAsync (null local path): generating a temporary file name for http://cache.thephoenix.com/secure/uploadedImages/The_Phoenix/Music/CD_Review/main_OTR_Britney480.jpg
DownloadFileTaskAsync (null local path): generating a temporary file name for http://ssimg.soundspike.com/artists/britneyspears_femmefatale_cd.jpg
DownloadFileTaskAsync (null local path): generating a temporary file name for http://a323.yahoofs.com/ymg/albumreviewsuk__1/albumreviewsuk-526650850-1301400550.jpg?ymm_1xEDE5bu0tMi
DownloadFileTaskAsync (null remote path): skipping
DownloadFileTaskAsync (time out due): http://hangout.altsounds.com/geek/gars/images/3/9/8/5/2375.jpg
DownloadFileTaskAsync (time out due): http://www.beat.com.au/sites/default/files/imagecache/630_315sr/images/article/header/2011/april/britney-spears-femme-fatale.jpg
DownloadFileTaskAsync (time out due): http://cache.thephoenix.com/secure/uploadedImages/The_Phoenix/Music/CD_Review/main_OTR_Britney480.jpg
DownloadFileTaskAsync (downloaded): http://newblog.thecmuwebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/britneyspears1.jpg
DownloadFileTaskAsync (downloaded): http://newblog.thecmuwebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/britneyspears1.jpg
DownloadFileTaskAsync (downloaded): http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Music/Pix/site_furniture/2011/3/22/1300816812640/Femme-Fatale.jpg
DownloadFileTaskAsync (downloaded): http://www.sputnikmusic.com/images/albums/72328.jpg
```

What used to take up to 1 minute now barely takes 10 seconds for the same result :)

And big thanks to the author of these 2 posts :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/05/10278165.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/04/10277325.aspx

Comment: Great extension methods!

Comment: Shouldn't the `await oneAtATime.WaitAsync();` be written before the `TResult result = await taskSelector(item);`? Otherwise you'd be just running immedietly the task for each item of your "source" and basically disregard the semaphore limitation (running only x tasks at a time)?

Comment: @BornToCode is absolutely correct. The code above, as written, will actually starts as many tasks as the TPL without the semaphore, and will instead only allow the `resultProcessor` to have a max DOP. **If you are cut and pasting the above code, move the .WaitAsync() above the execution of the taskselector.** Additionally, without calling `.Release(n)` on the semaphore, only `5` (not `10`) concurrent tasks will ever be running. I would recommend creating the semaphore as `... = new SemaphoneSlim(10,10)`

Answer (score -2):

For people coming here more recently like me, I just found that a `Parallel.ForEachAsync` was implemented in .NET 6: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-6.0.

Its usage is like you would expect, and it has the advantage of allowing to specify for the degree of parallelism. For example:

```cs
var someInputData = new []
{
    "someData1",
    "someData2",
    "someData3"
};

ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3
};
 
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(someInputData, parallelOptions, 
    async (input, cancellationToken) => 
    {
       // Some async Func. 
       // The Func can make use of:
       // - the `input` variable, which will contain the element in the `someInputData` list;
       // - the `cancellationToken` variable, usable to cancel the async operation.
    });
```

See also https://www.hanselman.com/blog/parallelforeachasync-in-net-6.

Comment: My understanding is that the OP wants to modify a `ForEachAsync` method that they found in the internet, so that it propagates the results of the asynchronous operations. Your answer doesn't address this requirement.

Comment: Alelom for my voting I took into consideration that you've posted an [identical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75976984/11178549) in a different question. Your answer is on-topic in the other question, so I upvoted that answer and downvoted this answer. It's unfortunate that the other answer has been deleted by a moderator. I might change my vote if you edit this answer in a way that it becomes on-topic here as well. FYI I've also downvoted this question and the other existing answer, because IMHO it's a confusing question with a bad self-answer.