# Thread.Sleep is terminating the current task

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a program that creates 10 parallel tasks and in each task I need to wait for 90 seconds and I am using `Thread.Sleep(90000)`. It is working fine, but some times it seems that it is terminating the current thread.Operations are waiting 90 seconds did not work.

Please suggest what will be the problem.

Comment: You can use `await Task.Delay(90)` for waiting per task which you want to delay in that!

Comment: will it pause the current task or all my 10 tasks?

Comment: no it will wait for a task who run this code at self

Comment: [Task.WaitAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx) to Waits for all of the provided Task objects to complete execution.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working with tasks I would suggest NOT working with thread.sleep. I suspect what you're looking for is [Task.Delay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194845(v=vs.110).aspx). For example

```
public async Task DoWork()
{
    await Task.Delay(90000);
}
```

This will delay the current task regardless of which thread it is being executed on and without interfering with other tasks.

Comment: How could that help with the issue in the question ("some times it seems that it is terminating the current thread")?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Thread.Sleep` when you want to block the current thread.

Use `Task.Delay` when you want a logical delay without blocking the current thread.

for example:

```
async Task PutTaskDelay()
{
    await Task.Delay(90000); // 9sec
}
```

Efficiency should not be a paramount concern with these methods. Their primary real-world use is as retry timers for I/O operations, which are on the order of seconds rather than milliseconds.

Comment: How could that help with the issue in the question ("some times it seems that it is terminating the current thread")?

Answer (score 1):

You  have to use **[Task.Delay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh194845(v=vs.110).aspx)**

```
  int N = 9;
  Parallel.For(0, N, async delegate(int i)
   {
                await Task.Delay(90000);
   });
```

### Edit:

Referring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284202/how-to-correctly-write-parallel-for-with-async-methods) **Parallel.For()** doesn't work well with **async** methods.

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(async i =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(90);
            });
 await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Never combine `Parallel.For` and `async`-`await`. It won't do what you think. Case in point: your code returns immediately, not after 90 s.

Comment: Yes @svick that is right thank you, i have to update my answer