# Optimising news fetching

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-7, optimization, web-scraping

I have a web scraper for scraping news from different sources in wp7.
My current appraoch for doing this is:

- load newspapers information from xml file.
- go to the specified sections and fetch the urls of the news items.
- go to each url and fetch headline, image, publisher.
- display using a MVVM architecture of windows phone.

The whole thing takes place asynchronously...meaning as soon as url from a section of a newspaper is fetched it is added to the queue, and the second stage consisting of fetching headline, image etc starts... and as soon this is fetched even for one article, it is displayed. Later on as more articles are fetched, they are added on to the list.

For the fetching purpose I am using a SmartThreadPool(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7933/Smart-Thread-Pool) for windows phone.

My problem is that...even for fetching around 80 items (in total) from 9 publications, it is taking more than a minute.
How can i speed up the procedure?

Note: I have a two stage approach because many times the images are not available with headlines, and are only found in the article.

Comment: What your **Profiler** says about this?

Comment: Perhaps that's just how long it takes for your phone's network connection to query all of that data.

Comment: @Servy My connection is quite reasonable...has got 3G speeds(around 3 MBPS). How do i speed it up at these speeds?

Answer (score 2):

It's not surprising that it takes more than a minute to make 80 web requests and get 80 responses. It typically takes at least 500 milliseconds between request and response even on a wired connection. Depending on the server and your connection, a full second of latency between request and response is not unreasonable. And that doesn't count the time it takes to download the content.

Your 3 Mbps link is three mega*bits* per second, or something less than 400 kilobytes per second, and that's going to be shared with everybody else who's using the same tower or connection point.

I'm not familiar with SmartThreadPool and I don't know how you're using it. It's likely, though, that it's limiting the number of concurrent threads, and you're using one thread per request. So if it limits you to 4 concurrent threads, then the best you can do is perhaps 4 downloads per second.

If instead you use a single thread that makes multiple asynchronous web requests, you can have 15 (possibly more) concurrent requests. Since the majority of the time spent in making web requests is spent waiting for a response from the server, this will give you a huge increase in performance over the other method. Assuming that the news articles you're downloading aren't so huge that your limiting factor is bandwidth.

From your description, I'd say that you don't need to do any *explicit* multithreading. Just use asynchronous web requests.

All that is speculation, of course, because you haven't shown any code or provided much in the way of detailed description. But if I were to write a news scraper like you describe, that's the approach I'd take.

Answer (score 0):

(wouldn't https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ be a better home for such question ?)

Things to consider :

**Images takes time to load, even on 3G or 4G phones**, skip or postpone their loading !

Take a look at how [NextGen reader](http://nextmatters.com/) does it on WP8 (also available for Win8) :

- It fetches excerpts of articles and shows them almost instantly
- When you tap on an article it loads it in its entirety (with pictures)
- If pictures are long to load, they're not shown, note that some sites wants a specific referrer whether for security reasons or for having their links accessed only through their site
- i.e. : many reasons for a picture to not load beside its size/your connection speed
- Still on the reader, when you tap the article title it opens the link in IE, I mean by doing that it's not your problem anymore as people are surfing and not using your application

In my opinion you should make your application to work sufficiently fast but it doesn't have to be perfect (especially the images part), with time people will quickly understand that it's not your application's fault if images are missing but those sites (which is true by the way).

You could take a look at the desktop app. with Fiddly to see what it does exactly.

I've been using this reader everyday for months on my WP8, I'm satisfied with this behavior, I know that for missing images (more exactly, on certain websites) I either have to browse the site itself or just forget about it and I don't blame the application for that.

---

Now **I had a similar problem**, asked a question that in the end I answered myself :

I needed to load many images from many different sources, it had to be fast. The most blocking issue were time-outs as they are very long/annoying to wait for. I ended up skipping the loading of sluggish images and I am very happy about it though a few of them are not visible :

[image]

There are a few more images that are unavailable but perceptually it's not as important as the content is here : text and links to original website. And you can always try loading again in background.

The code I posted is sufficient for my needs, if a picture takes more than 3 seconds then I just skip it. I can try loading it again later but the most important part of my application  is here  : **responsiveness**. In addition to this, I download things in parallel for which I invite you to take a look at the answer I posted below :

[Asynchronously and parallelly downloading files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189275/asynchronously-and-parallelly-downloading-files)

Extra things to consider : cache images